# how to tag a friend using FB graph API?

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to tag a friend in FB message to be posted, I am using PHP,  and for FB I am using FB Auth API 2.0, I have tried to get related information from facebook developers forum, however can't find enough information for this one. 
Can anyone suggest me from where to get started for this? any links to related documentation or forum links using which I can get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `message_tags` field of the `Post` object. Check out [the docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/):

> message_tags: object containing fields whose names are the indexes to
>   where objects are mentioned in the message field; each field in turn
>   is an array containing an object with id, name, offset, and length
>   fields, where length is the length, within the message field, of the
>   object mentioned

Comment: I just found out related question for this, here is the link,
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8341373/how-to-use-the-message-tags-parameter-in-the-post

Comment: is it true that "there's no way to add tags to posts via the API" as mentioned in above comment?

Comment: I don't know what comment you're talking about, but the answer is clearly **no**, as you probably already noticed ;)

Comment: comment posted by user at thread http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8341373/how-to-use-the-message-tags-parameter-in-the-post

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
    $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
    $tags = array(
    ‘tag_text’ => ‘ak Yip’,
    ‘tag_uid’ => 642536423,//it’s my id on facebook as a sample
    ‘x’ => 10,
    ‘y’ => 10,
    );

    $args['tags'] = array($tags);
    $args['image'] = ‘@’ . realpath($fn);
    $data = $facebook->api(‘/me/photos’, ‘post’, $args);
```

Note:
**One:Your app need to get permissions like ‘user_photo_video_tags’ and ‘friends_photo_video_tags’.

Two:X,Y is proportion, not coordinate. Don’t put value over 100.**